# XML, how to add a local element to existing document that uses an external DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an XML document that uses an external DTD.  I cannot modify the DTD.  I would like to add an element to the data, because it would make my life MUCH simpler.

Since I can't modify the DTD, is there a way to define an element IN the XML file and place it in a node from the DTD?  If so, how?

(I mean, defining another element is pretty straightforward, but I want it to appear between two existing child nodes in the DTD.  This is the part that is stumping me.

Existing DTD declaration from file:

```
<!DOCTYPE partslist PUBLIC "-//USA//TM Assembly REV 6.0 //EN" "TM.dtd">
```

Relevant snippet of DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT partslist (intro, mrpl)>
<!ELEMENT mrpl (mrpentry, mrpentry+)>
<!ELEMENT mrpentry (itemno, partno, vendorid, stocknum, name, qty)>
```

I would like to define an element `<!ELEMENT mypn?>`.
I would like it to be a child node of `<mrpentry>`, appearing between `<vendorid>` and `<stocknum>`.

I can update the DTD declaration to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE partslist PUBLIC "-//USA//TM Assembly REV 6.0 //EN" "TM.dtd" [
<!ELEMENT mypn (#CDATA)>
]>
```

That does not parse.

I suspect XML won't actually let me mix both a DTD and locally defined elements, but it would be the easy solution to my problem.

EDIT:  I tried standalone="no".    Added my child element to mrpentry, and added the element itself. I was doubtful that this would work.  I did not think I could redefine an element that was already defined in the DTD.

Notepad++ thinks this is OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE partslist PUBLIC "-//USA//TM Assembly REV 6.0 //EN" "TM.dtd" [
<!ELEMENT mrpentry (itemno, partno, vendorid, mypn?, stocknum, name, qty)>
<!ELEMENT mypn (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

I tried it in Arbortext, and Arbortext did not like it.

Error: An ELEMENT declaration is not supported in the declaration subset. Parsing is terminated.

Oxygen was a little more forthcoming:

Element type "mrpentry" must not be declared more than once.

Which I already suspected. Sigh.

Back to the drawing board.  Added my part number as an attribute, which is still OK, even if less useful. Oxygen thought this parsed OK.  Notepad++ thought it was OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE partslist PUBLIC "-//USA//TM Assembly REV 6.0 //EN" "TM.dtd" [
<!ATTLIST mrpentry mypn CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Arbortext does not parse the new attribute and flags all my test attributes as errors.

ERROR: Unrecognized attribute "mypn" for tag "mrpentry"

I guess the real test is how the publishing software deals with it.  Ideally, it will just ignore the extra attribute, and not report them as errors.

Thanks for the tip on standalone.

Comment: See https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_combined_dtd.cfm

Comment: Also https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/doctype_declaration.shtml and pay attention to `standalone=no`

Comment: Thanks, Jim.  That sort of worked. Still could not manage to add an extra child to an already defined element, but that's a different problem.